# Trouble loading PDF.js lib in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, pdf, static-resources

I have trouble loading the PDF.js library in my Lightning Web Component. Whenever I load the page with the component, I get :

> PDF.js could not be loaded undefined

Twice, this additional error popped up in Edge:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Firefox prints the latter error a bit differently and also specifies the path of the module, for example: https://myOrg.lightning.force.com/resource/pdfjs/build/pdf.mjs

Here is the code I am using to load the library:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {loadScript} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import pdfjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfjs';

export default class LinkField extends LightningElement {
    
connectedCallback(){
        Promise.all([ loadScript(this, pdfjs) ]).then(()=>{ console.log('loaded'); })
              .catch(error=>{ console.error("PDF.js could not be loaded " + error); });
    }
...
```

And a screenshot of my static resource:
[image: Static resource page]

Since I am not able to find proper documentation on how to load or use libraries/static resources in LWC, even just a pointer to some documentation or appropriate coding examples, would be appreciated.

**Edit**

After changing to the older version V3.11.174 of PDF.js, which contains .js instead of .mjs files, the previously stated MIME type errors disappeared and the pdf viewer I put into an iframe is not completely without function anymore.
I am still unable to load the scripts of the library however and continue to receive the same error:

> PDF.js could not be loaded undefined

This also continuous to happen when I specifiy the paths to the individual .js files, like so:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import pdfjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfjs';

export default class LinkField extends LightningElement {

connectedCallback(){
        Promise.all([ loadScript(this, pdfjs + "/build/pdf.js") ])
            .then(()=>{ console.log('loaded'); })
            .catch(error=>{ console.error("PDF.js could not be loaded " + error); });
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `loadScript` you need to point it to the `.js` file in your static resource, not just the folder name.

For example, instead of `loadScript(this, pdfjs)`, you need to do `loadScript(this, pdfjs + "/build/pdf.js")`. (Refer to the static resource to get the correct file name)

There is some documentation for this: [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-third-party-library.html)

Also, when catching a Javascript error, you should do `error.message` to get the error message.

Comment: When I try to use `loadScript(this, pdfjs + "/build/pdf.mjs")` I am still getting the same errors. Could it be because of the file type?

Comment: Is there a `.js` file you can use? The version of pdfjs I looked at had `/build/pdf.js`

Comment: I found V3.11.174 of PDF.js, which still uses .js files. While the MIME type errors disappeared, I am still unable to load individual files from the library.

Comment: Update your question with the code you are using to do this

Comment: I did so. I also turned LWS back on, since I had the suspicion that Lightning Locker could be the culprit, but this didn't change the behavior in any way I was able to notice.

Comment: Btw, change `error` to `error.message` in your catch. That'll help give you some more information

Comment: Doing that, I get `Lightning Web Security: platformResourceLoader error loading '/resource/1699626137000/pdfjs/build/pdf.js'.`

Comment: When I use error.message, loadScript is successful for me. There are other problems I am now facing, but I am thankful for your help.